# How can I check or verify that a user is signed in with AWS Cognito Javascript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am creating a React web app where the user sign in/up and other authentication related processes are being handled by AWS Cognito and the accompanying [Javascript SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js).

My app has some 'public' routes/pages that everybody, signed in or not, can view, such as /documentation/ and /sign-in/. There also exist various private routes which you can only see when you are logged in, such as /my-documents/.

At the moment, I have a working sign in page, where a user is signed in with code very similar to [use case #4 (Cognito Docs)](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js).

My question now is: as soon as a user goes to /my-documents/, how do I check whether the user is signed in and actually has the rights to see this page?

I am not using AWS Amplify for the authentication in my app. I only use the NPM package 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'.

This is the code I currently use to check if the session is valid, in other words if the user is successfully signed in. This however, seems like a cumbersome way to check such a simple status.

```
const isAuthenticated = () => {
  const cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

  let isSessionValid = false;

  if (cognitoUser) {
    cognitoUser.getSession((err: Error, result: CognitoUserSession) => {
      if (!err) {
        isSessionValid = result.isValid();
      }
    });
  }

  return isSessionValid;
};
```

Comment: Where are the user's documents stored?

Comment: In a Postgress DB, served via Lambdas in an API Gateway

Comment: Ok, and are you using cognito to protect apigateway API rote so that only logged in user can use that API and be able to get his own document from postgres based on id of the document?

Comment: I am planning on doing that, but I am having a hard time getting and storing the JWT Id token, because now I would need to call getSession() to get this token every time I make a request. I would love to just access this value right away

Comment: As far as I'm aware your tokens are stored on localstorage by amplify. Getsession is useful as it refreshes tokens if they are expired. So you can check if localstorage has tokens saved to protect your documents route on front end. Then make API call to fetch documents and if you get any error that is authentication related, redirect user to login page.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at the tokens!

Answer (score -1):

`isSessionValid` is returned before the callback in `getSession` is executed.

Comment: Its not answer to question. Could you please add it in the comment of another answer?